# Testing Securely Call the Visualforce Remoting API

Tags: remote-action, release-update

In my org I tried to test the Securely Call the Visualforce Remoting API is their any impact to existing @remote action. So I enabled the Visualforce Remoting API Release. Now I created an VF and apex class for remote action. And it seems working fine with out {"apexType": "Object"} as parameter if Visualforce Remoting API Release is enabled. Now I need to test by passing the {"apexType": "Object"} as parameter for remote action, do anyone know how to use this security parameter as a part of @remote action.

Reference doc : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_vf_js_remoting_security_ru.htm&type=5&release=232

VF code :

```
<apex:page controller="TestRemoteActionCriticalUpdate_Apex">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script>
    function getRemoteContact() {
        var a;
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            //Invoking controller action getcon
            '{!$RemoteAction.TestRemoteActionCriticalUpdate_Apex.getcon}',
            function(result, event){
                //We can access the records through the parameter result
                //event.status determines if there is error or not 
                if(event.status){
                    //document.getElementById('remoteContactId').innerHTML = 'Contact Name :- <br/><br/>';
                    for(a=0; a < result.length; a++){                        
                        document.getElementById('remoteContactId').innerHTML +=  a +'. ' + result[a].Name +'<br/>';                    
                    }                                       
                }
            },
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
</script>
<button onclick="getRemoteContact()">Get Contact</button>
<div id="responseErrors"></div>
<apex:pageBlock id="block">        
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="blockSection" columns="2">
            <span id="remoteContactId"></span>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Apex :

```
global  with sharing  class TestRemoteActionCriticalUpdate_Apex {

@RemoteAction 
global static list<Contact> getcon() {
    list<Contact> con = [SELECT id, name FROM contact limit 20];
    if(con != null && !con.isEmpty()){        
        return con;        
    }else{        
        return  new list<contact>();        
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The security parameter is passed in as the second parameter. This is in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_remote_method_interface_params.htm):

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  //Invoking controller action getcon
  '{!$RemoteAction.TestRemoteActionCriticalUpdate_Apex.getcon}',
  {apexType:'TestRemoteActionCriticalUpdate_Apex'},
  function(result, event){
```

This is normal JavaScript object with the parameters laid out. Since you don't have any parameters, this is the only parameter you need.

By the way, the result of a query is never null, so you can just return it directly:

```
@RemoteAction 
global static list<Contact> getcon() {
    return [SELECT id, name FROM contact limit 20];
}
```

Comment: Currently in my org the Javascript remoting VF pages are not having "apexType" in the parameter. Could you please explain me whether we need to add "apexType" parameter in all the Javascript remoting VF pages in my org as a part of this release update.